# Edit stat_smooth lines AND geom_points in the same figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph with points from multiple levels of a categorical variable and the relevant loess smoothing lines for each level of the same variable.  I need to edit BOTH the points AND the lines as in order convert the default colour graph to a meaningful black and white graph. I can edit the points using scale_shape_manual but not the lines. The following code uses mtcars to get close to what I need. Unfortunately all the liens are the same color (red)I suspect I don't understand where these sorts of ?aesthetic? commands should be placed. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg, shape=factor(cyl)))
c + 
  stat_smooth(method=loess, size = 1, col="red") + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), size = 4) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,22, 1))
```

[image: ggplot produced by this code]

Comment: If you find the answer below useful, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that others know this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways select specific colors for discrete and gradient scales in `ggplot2`, mostly centering around usage of the `scale_color_...` and `scale_fill_...` functions here in a similar way to how you have used `scale_shape_manual()`.

Since you're looking for grayscale, it's probably most straightforward to having those scales selected automatically for you using the convenience functions `scale_color_grey()` and `scale_fill_grey()`.

Finally, in order to have `ggplot2` select the color of each line, you need to have the legend created for that and place the `color=` aesthetic within `aes()`.  You had `col=` (another way to indicate `color=`) outside of `aes()` for `stat_smooth()`, so all lines were drawn with that color.  I believe this is what you are looking to do:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg, shape=factor(cyl))) +
  stat_smooth(method=loess, size = 1, aes(color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,22, 1)) +
  scale_color_grey() + scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

You'll notice it's hard to see the lightest line color.  You can fix that by applying a bit of transparency to the fill around `geom_smooth()` via `alpha=` and also changing to the `theme_bw()` to have a white background:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg, shape=factor(cyl))) + theme_bw() +
  stat_smooth(method=loess, size = 1, aes(color=factor(cyl)), alpha=0.18) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,22, 1)) +
  scale_color_grey() + scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]